# ow to change cutsom page url of wordpress site using htaccess

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

i need help in httaccess rewrite of a wordpress site. i have url like below

http://thewhiterabbit.dk/beta/steder-detail/?id=floos

i want it to be like

http://thewhiterabbit.dk/beta/steder-detail/floos

i have developed using id=floos, now instead of redeveloping all thing i just want a rule to change the url

any help will be greatly appriciated thanks.

Comment: yes i am using custom permalinks

Comment: /%postname%/ this is i have in cutom structure field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you shouldn't use .htaccess directly when working with WordPress. WordPress has powerful [rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) allowing you to do the stuff from plugins or theme's functions.php

If you need the id=floos on more than one page, consider using [rewrite endpoints](https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/):

```
function makeplugins_add_json_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'floos', EP_PAGES );
}
add_action( 'init', 'makeplugins_add_json_endpoint' );
```

To determinate, whether floos is set up, you check like this:

```
global $wp_query
if ( is_page() && isset( $wp_query->query_vars['json'] )  ) { ... }
```

If you need that only for a specific page and the "id" value can change, you'll have to use standard wp_rewrite stuff:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'binda_query_vars' );
function binda_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'id';
    return $vars;
}

add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'binda_rewrite_rules' );
function binda_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite )
{
    $page = get_post( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'name' => 'steder-detail' );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array(
        'steder-detail/(.*)/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . 'page_id=' . $page->ID . '&id=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ),
    ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

The value of ID would be accessible as follows:

```
get_query_var( 'ID' );
```

PS: Both codes should go either to functions.php, or better to [site-specific plugin](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/what-why-and-how-tos-of-creating-a-site-specific-wordpress-plugin/).

Comment: thanks for detail reply. but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: i used standered wp_rewrite http://dev.evsoft.pk/rabbit_um/steder-detail/floss/
takes me to home page

Comment: I guess the problem part would be $page = get_page_by_path( 'steder-detail' ); Try to change it to $page = get_post( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'name' => 'steder-detail' ); or hardcode $page_id = 14 //whatever your ID of steder-detail page is and use $page_id in wp_rewrite rule instead of $page->ID

Comment: your answer helpd . 
i used code below and worked some how. 
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'binda_query_vars' );
function binda_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'std';
  
 return $vars;
}



add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'binda_rewrite_rules' );
function binda_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite )
{

    $page = get_page_by_path( 'steder-detail' );
 $wp_rewrite->rules = array(
        'steder-detail/(.*)([^/]+)$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?page_id=' . $page->ID . '&std=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
    ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
 
}